# My application is getting this weird error with TNS but

Tags: vb.net, oracle, tnsnames, tns

VB.Net app is getting this error. However when i open SQL Plus from command prompt, I can connect with no problem

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I am not sure what to do here.

I can also connect with SQL Developer
Visual Studio's Server Explorer can see the database as well.

Comment: please edit the question and post a [mcve]

Comment: What data provider are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that instead of specifying a short name for the Data Source wherever your connection string is, just putting the whole connection description can solve issues like this. More of a work-around you can do if you don't want to chase down the specific configuration problem on the machine, but I haven't had it fail yet.

So if your TNSNames file has:

```
MYSID=

  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mydnshostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYSID)
    )
  )
```

and your connection string in web.config looks something like like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MYSID;User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

you can do this instead in the configuration file:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = mydnshostname)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = MYSID)));User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` client you might want to set a path to the TNSnames file in your application.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\OracleTNS" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Comment: my app doesn't have an application.config file. Can I just create it?

Comment: Yup! In the same directory as `YourAppName.exe` just create a `YourAppName.exe.config`